# Constant defined in initializer not found within helper namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have stored a constant in `config/initializers/constants/feature_constants.rb` called

```
NEW_CONTACT_US = 'https://ruby-on-rails.com/contact-us/'
```

In my helper method, I have a function as:

```
def link_for_users?
    link = if current_user.new_user?
      NEW_CONTACT_US
    else
      OLD_CONTACT_US
    end
    link
  end
```

My view file looks like this:

```
= render partial: 'design/buttons/disabled', locals: {button_title: "Enable feature", tooltip_title: "Upgrade", tooltip_message: "Click here", contact_us_link: link_for_users?}
```

this gives me:

```
uninitialized constant FeaturesHelper::NEW_CONTACT_US
```

Comment: The method should be named `link_for_users` not `link_for_users?`. Any method ending with `?` is by convention a interogration method and should return a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is correct behavior since the lookup for the constant is within the helper. You need to define the constant actually within the helper and it will work perfect

```
module FeaturesHelper
  NEW_CONTACT_US = "https://....".freeze
  def link_for_users?
    current_user.new_user? ? NEW_CONTACT_US : OLD_CONTACT_US
  end
end
```